# Change content in same parent clip? (Premiere Pro)

Tags: premiere, adobe, premiere-elements

I downloaded a library that comes with a sequence called Typo_06. I want to use Typo_06 several times in my project with different images and text changed inside it. Whenever I edit anything on Typo_06, it edits it for all of the Typo_06 sequence. Is there a way to have each of these sequences independent? I've tried duplicating into its own sequence for each and creating a whole new sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here (the one selected as best answer): https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/copying-a-sequence-using-premier-pro-cc-2019/td-p/10450703?page=1